# Javascript, targeting the parent element: Why is the event not triggered?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to solve a task given by a javascript textbook.
The code is supposed to trigger an event whenever the mouse is over one of the five divs. It should count up (and of course show the counter's change in the HTML) whenever the event is triggered. But it obviously doesn't do the job and I am clueless why.

Hope you can help.

HTML

```
<div id="one"><a id="pick-one">0</a></div>
<div id="two"><a id="pick-two">0</a></div>
<div id="three"><a id="pick-three">0</a></div>
<div id="four"><a id="pick-four">0</a></div>
<div id="five"><a id="pick-five">0</a></div>
```

JS

```
var counter = 0;

function count(event){
counter++; event.target.parentElement.innerHTML = counter;
}

function setup(){
var pages = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("pick-" +
pages[i]).addEventListener("mouseover", count);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);

}
```

Comment: because your `window.addEventListener("load", setup)` is inside the setup function. Move it out

Comment: thanks for the advice. I did it and it makes total sense, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: is your script in different file? is the script is inline

Comment: I update my answer (below)

Comment: the script is in a different file but these two are "well connected". i've been working with these two files trying other little self written code and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Remove line `window.addEventListener("load", setup);` and write

```
setup();
```

as the last line of your script (and remember to link script file at the bottom of your `<body>`)

**UPDATE**

Your comment:

> and actually the code is supposed to count until whatever number, not
>   just from one to five

Change

```
event.target.parentElement.innerHTML = counter;
```

to

```
event.target.innerHTML = counter;
```

here is working [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z2q9aejL/2/)

Comment: but why? and actually the code is supposed to count until whatever number, not just from one to five... I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Nat_ try to notice it from your code, you did replaced the `a href` as well

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Dean's comment, you should put the load event outside the loop. *The other part that's missing is the parentheses*:

```
window.addEventListener("load", setup());
```

**EDIT 2** Actually this is wrong, the reason it works with parentheses is because it executes the function and then assigns the return to the onLoad event. Which is not the desired behaviour. The reason the onLoad event doesn't trigger in the fiddle is because:

[image: JSFiddle onLoad]

[Edited working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2q9aejL/3/)

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

I saw your comment, the reason why it doesn't keep couting is because you are changing the parents innerHTML, instead of the innerHTML of `<a>`, try this:

```
counter++; event.target.innerHTML = counter;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to move function call from setup function.

Second, it count to five because you replace the whole link with a counter, and not only the value of it.

To solve this you can try something like this:

```js
var counters = {
 one: 0,
  two: 0,
  three: 0,
  four: 0,
  five: 0
}

function count(event){
  var id = event.target.id;
  var parentId = event.target.parentElement.id;
  counters[parentId] = counters[parentId] + 1;
  
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = counters[parentId];
}

function setup(){
  var pages = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
      document.getElementById("pick-" + pages[i]).addEventListener("mouseover", count);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setup(), false);
```

```html
<div id="one"><a id="pick-one">0</a></div>
<div id="two"><a id="pick-two">0</a></div>
<div id="three"><a id="pick-three">0</a></div>
<div id="four"><a id="pick-four">0</a></div>
<div id="five"><a id="pick-five">0</a></div>
```

Thus in your `count` function get first the id of the element with `var id = event.target.id;`, and pass then add the counter.

Or you can also just change `event.target.parentElement.innerHTML = counter;` to `event.target.innerHTML = counter;`

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ty9fndzc/)

**UPDATE**

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ty9fndzc/1/)

Comment: thank you very much, this comes close to the solution. but there is just a tiny little thing... each <a> is supposed to count only it's own "touches". so if my mouse is over "one" it should count 1. if my mouse is over "two" it should count 1. you know what I mean?

Comment: @Nat_ You need then different counters for each link.

Comment: That's helpul. Thanks! And it obviously helps, but I've got a question: "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setup(), false);" why the "false" at the end?

Comment: @Nat_ Here is the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="one"><a id="pick-one">0</a></div>
<div id="two"><a id="pick-two">0</a></div>
<div id="three"><a id="pick-three">0</a></div>
<div id="four"><a id="pick-four">0</a></div>
<div id="five"><a id="pick-five">0</a></div>

var counter = 0;
window.onLoad =  setup();

function count(event){
counter++; event.target.parentElement.innerHTML = counter;
}

function setup(){
var pages = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("pick-" +
pages[i]).addEventListener("mouseover", count);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register the parent of multiple `event.target`s and listen for events on all off them with one `eventListener()`. In this Demo, we have the mouseover event registered to `document`. We then use `event.target` to determine what exact element was hovered over and then accept only what we actually want by `if/else` condition. For details on using only one `eventListener()` for an unlimited amount of elements, read this article on **[Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)**.

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo**

```js
// Register the mouseover event on document
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {

  // Declare counter outside of callback function
  var counter = 0;

  // Pass Event Object and counter 
  count(e, counter);
});



function count(e, counter) {

  // increment counter
  counter++;

  // if the event origin element (e.target) is a <a> element...
  if (e.target.tagName === "A") {

    // Convert its text into a real number
    var num = parseInt(e.target.textContent, 10);

    // Then add the counter to e.target's content
    e.target.textContent = counter + num;

    // Otherwise...
  } else {

    // Quit
    return false;
  }
  // Return e.target's content (not used in this demo)
  return e.target.textContent;
}
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
}

div {
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <a id="pick-one">0</a>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <a id="pick-two">0</a>
</div>
<div id="three">
  <a id="pick-three">0</a>
</div>
<div id="four">
  <a id="pick-four">0</a>
</div>
<div id="five">
  <a id="pick-five">0</a>
</div>
```

Comment: cool! question: "var num = parseInt(e.target.textContent, 10);
    e.target.textContent = counter + num;" -> where does the "10" come from? why is it there?

Comment: That's the second parameter of `parseInt(n, radix)` the radix is what base the return will be. Normally it's base 10, if you pass in 2 the return will be binary, if you pass in 16 it'll be hexadecimal.